# OpenCart automatically add new products

Tags: opencart

I have to write code which will automatically add/delete/edit products on that opencart website, so my question is the following :

How to add new products to the database automatically with php?there are some methods in opencart, so I can use them, or I have to write the code from scratch

P.S: an example will be great (suppose we have the product information in an array)

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am doing something similar to this, my setup is as follows:

1. Script: this is where the items are added, deleted or updated. I write directly into the database tables `(product, product_description, product_to_store, category_id, product_to_category)` by use of MySQL statements.
2. Since my sync happens concurrently, I have a CRON job triggering the script.
3. Logging: to keep track of whats happening I added a database table called `log` where I keep a record of what files are being processed, at what time, errors etc.

My conclusion is that you should create a model and controller which will handle this request to automatically add/delete/edit products and then whenever you need to run this you can just navigate to that script. Another clever thing to do would be to secure that script on the back-end so that only you are able to navigate to it.

---

**An example of a MySQL insert statement for products as follows:**

```
 $insert_product = "INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product ( sku, quantity, stock_status_id, status, date_added, price, taxpercentage, supplier, department, webshop, schedule)
         VALUES ('".$sku."','" .$onhand. "','7','1',NOW(),'".$price. "','" .$tax_percentage. "','" .$supplier. "','" .$department. "','" . $webshop . "','" .$schedule. "')";
```